# Recognition of small barcode on playing cards

Tags: zxing

I'm trying to use zxing to detect small barcodes on playing cards for the purpose of scanning all hands after a game of bridge for easy analysis of the game.

I have looked at the GenericMultipleBarcodeReader class which seems to do exactly what I want. However, there already seems to be a problem in recognizing even one barcode. I believe that they are too small for easy recognition: even calling the detect method on an instance of MonochromeRectangleDetector class results in a NotFoundException.

I have attached an example image to give an idea of what the cards look like. Does anyone have suggestions on how to approach this problem, or are the barcodes just too small for zxing to recognize them? The official zxing Android app also does not detect any barcode if I use it on the playing card.

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol33q.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize that as any known barcode format. Are you sure it is not just some marking, or some custom format? certainly this is why it is not read.

Comment: It is a barcode format, but it might be a special format. The format is as follows (from left to right):
1 black line, 1 white line, 9 black/white lines, 1 white line, 1 black line.
Thus it is a 9-bits barcode, but I don't know if it's according to a specific standard.

Comment: Also, even detection of 'something that looks like a barcode' is not working (with the MonochromeRectangleDetector class). This should just look for a black and white region in the image. It also does not detect anything when I crop the image to just contain the barcode.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what format that is. You would have to write a reader for it. That is not what `MonochromeRectangleDetector` does; it has no role in 1D barcodes. These are not rectangles.

Comment: Oh okay. Is there any class which can detect the left and right points of a barcode in a picture, or would I have to write that part as well? Once I have the coordinates of the left and right boundaries it should be simple to write something that does the rest.

Comment: Of course, but what the left and right boundaries look like are specific to a format. Finding a black bar is easy but far from sufficient. Look at how the other readers work.